# What type of crimp terminals are these?

Tags: connector, automotive

In my vehicle, I have a 27-pin connector with Volkswagen OEM part number **8K0 972 701** (male) / **8K0 972 702** (female). Etched onto it is the TE Connectivity logo and the number 1718872-1. I am looking for crimp terminals for this connector.

[image: 8K0 972 702 connector]

The terminals look like this for the narrow pins:

[image: narrow female pin]
[image: narrow male pin]

and for the wider pins:

[image: wide female pin]
[image: wide male pin]

I have found plenty of places to buy the connector *housings* with the given information. However, how would I go about finding the correct matching **crimp terminals** to attach to my wires? As you can see, pins 18 - 23 are wider, so I would require two different types of terminals.

Any general pointers to where or how to search, or even an exact answer as to which terminals to use would be greatly appreciated. Is there some type of standard? I have already found some [pigtail connectors](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32865094796.html), but I would rather crimp the wires myself.

---

**Update**

To anyone also looking for this information, I have [found](http://www.mksautobusiness.fi/data/26%20pin-1.pdf) the OEM numbers of some pre-crimped cables that seem to fit on this connector (not entirely sure).

**Male:**

- 000 979 022 (wide pin, 0.35 mm² wire)
- 000 979 035 (narrow pin, 0.35 mm² wire)
- 000 979 134 (wide pin, 1 mm² wire)
- 000 979 160 (narrow pin, 1 mm² wire)
- 000 979 226 (wide pin, 2.5 mm² wire)

**Female:**

- 000 979 026 (wide pin, 0.35 mm² wire)
- 000 979 034 (narrow pin, 0.35 mm² wire)
- 000 979 151 (wide pin, 1 mm² wire)
- 000 979 159 (narrow pin, 1 mm² wire)
- 000 979 242 (wide pin, 2.5 mm² wire)

Part number + suffix A seems to be for gold-coated contacts and suffix C for silver-coated contacts, from what I can see.

As these parts are kind of expensive I would still be very interested in what type of crimping terminals they use so I can make these wires myself!

Comment: A google search for "979 terminals" brings up lots of places selling them.  Ebay and Aliexpress seems to have lots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. According to [this page (German)](https://www.a4-freunde.com/showwiki.php?title=Pins%20und%20alles%20was%20dazu%20gehoert#vw-head-10), the connectors for the narrow pins are of the **TE Connectivity MCON 1.2** type. There are two variants, with Volkswagen using the *locking lace (LL)* type. The wider pins seem to be **TE Connectivity MCP 2.8** type.

I will order them now. I'll update this answer if they end up not fitting.